# Android Background Service Working at Emulator but not at phone

Tags: android, android-service, background-service

I developed an android application that starts an android background service. This service sets alarms on the selected time instances. This application and the service is working absolutely fine on android emulator. Works as I expected it to. But the strange thing happens when I installed this application at my android phone. The application worked fine, it started the android service too. But nothing happened from there on. I checked the settings-apps-running apps at my phone. It showed that the service is running on phone. But the thing that I expected from the service was to ring alarms at selected time instances, which it didn't at my phone. I have a samsung galaxy nexus phone. Can you please diagnose what is the problem actually?

Comment: Try putting logs and see if any execution is happening ?

Comment: Is there something up with your phone settings preventing alarms?

Comment: Did you check the logcat on the phone for any errors or other messages.